# Integrating REST and Play Framework into LAMP system under development

Tags: java, php, scala, rest, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a huge system that is under development on a standard LAMP stack. Long story short, too many mistakes have been made and our current development vector is becoming unsustainable. Problems that we have in summary:

- Custom and very basic PHP MVC framework is being used which doesn't enforce any structure.
- No ORM is used, allowing developers to come up with each their own system.
- Front end is rendered by Smarty, apart from that all the dynamic interaction is done with jQuery.
- We have some heavy processing in parts of the system where PHP is failing / being very slow.
- No unit testing is used
- REST is only used for some APIs to external systems
- The PHP framework doesn't support dependency injection

I will not mention other problems that contribute to the system becoming a total mess, I consider these to be the main ones.

I'd like to turn the development of the system to a different direction by introducing something similar what Twitter uses - system split in modules connected with REST (if my assumption is correct). These are things I'd like to introduce:

- Play Framework (Java/Scala)
- Connect Play with existing LAMP stack via REST
- Switch Apache to Nginx
- (most likely) use Angular.js for the front end.
- In long term convert the whole existing LAMP to Play

Main issue I'm facing and would appreciate any advice on is:

- How would I maintain / pass the state, bearing in mind that REST is stateless? Our current LAMP obviously uses PHP sessions for this.

Any other comments about this particular situation are also welcome.

Comment: Can you make changes in your existing LAMP Stack? For example moving from PHP Sessions to memcached, redis or someother keystore database?

Comment: @ViniciusMiana Problem is, current LAMP stack is on the way to doom and since we have to redo a lot of the code, I'd rather choose a superior stack.

Comment: To connect X with existing LAMP stack via REST, you need to create this REST API on your existing stack. One approach is to move the state out the Php to something that will last after the php is gone. Your api will be stateless, but passes a key to the state that is stored in this store, which can be updated directly by new functions written in Scala/Java or whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What state do you want to share?  The current logged in user?  Anything else?  And what do you want to share it with?  Between different Play nodes?  Between Play and your LAMP stack?

If the amount of state is small, and also if it's not sensitive (ie it's ok for the current user to see that state), then you can use Play's sessions.  Play sessions are completely stateless, they store the state in a cookie, and sign the cookie to prevent tampering.  More information here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaSessionFlash

If you used the same application secret for each of your Play modules (the application secret is what's used to sign/verify the session cookie), then they'll all be able to share state using that mechanism.  You could even share that state with your existing LAMP stack, you'd just have to implement Play cookie signing algorithm in PHP.

If the state is larger, eg you're using it to cache things, or if you want to store state that might be sensitive, then something like memcached might work well for you.